# GridLayout as child of Scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I try to put a GridLayout into a Scrollview. But it doesn't work.
Does it work at all (according to this link: [http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/3432/GridLayout-Sample-(EditText-Spinner)](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/3432/GridLayout-Sample-%28EditText-Spinner%29))?

Here is my code:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:useDefaultMargins="true"
            android:rowCount="10"
            android:columnCount="3">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Settings_Generally"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="0"/>


        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/PathToFiles_local"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Settings_Network"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/IPAddress"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Username"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Password"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Domain"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_row="7"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/PathToFiles_network"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_row="8"
                android:layout_column="0"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etPathToLocalFiles"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etIPAddress"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etDomain"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_row="7"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/etPathToNetworkFiles"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_row="8"
                android:layout_column="1"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/SelectFiles"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:onClick="SelectLocalDirectory_Click"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/SelectFiles"
                android:layout_row="8"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:onClick="SelectNetworkDirectory_Click"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/CheckConnection"
                android:layout_row="9"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:onClick="CheckConnection_Click"/>

    </GridLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview inside scrollview not a good idea

Comment: i don't have any scrollview inside of this scrollview...

Comment: @SimonHilner he meant to say that even `GridView` has scrolling effect as `ListView`. So no need to use `ScrollView`.

Comment: But i'm using a GridLayout. Not a GridView.

Comment: Why can't i scroll a GridLayout? Can nobody help me? :D

Comment: what I meant was gridlayout is gridlayout is scrollable. Also scrollview is scrollable. When user try to scroll your gridlayout which is inside scrollview what will you scroll gridlayout or scrollview?? This will bring inconsistency as which element is to receive the event of scrolling. Try searching scrollview inside scrollview

Comment: Sorry but how could this help me? 
I tried to make the GridLayout scrollable but it doesn't work (with and without scrollview). Do you have a running example?